# List of values can't be removed from Crystal report

Tags: c#, visual-studio, crystal-reports

I created a report with Crystal Report and i added a group in this rouport.
The problem here is a duplicated values appear on right of the table and i can't remove them fom the report.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Right Click on section field and check suppress if duplicate option